# VBA - web scraping can not find correct GET request

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

My question is related to other question [VBA - web scraping can not get HTMLElement innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028019/vba-web-scraping-can-not-get-htmlelement-innertext). I have a similar problem

Website URL - https://www.hnb.hr/en/core-functions/monetary-policy/exchange-rate-list/exchange-rate-list

I need to get the date of currency reference and the selected values. The problem is that I can not find a correct `GET` request where these values are finally generated. I've found that it is related to the `POST` request:

`POST` /en/core-functions/monetary-policy/exchange-rate-list/exchange-rate-list?p_p_id=tecajnalistacontroller_WAR_hnbtecajnalistaportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=getTecajnaAjaxDataURL&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=2 HTTP/1.1

I would like to use a technique with getting by id, class or tag - whatever but again, provided `GET` URL request is too quick to retrieve the required info

Comment: The content of that webpage gets loaded via javascript. You should either follow what QHarr has already suggested or use IE to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **XMLHTTP request and API:**

I would use their [API](http://hnbex.eu/api/v1/) as shown below. I have some helper functions to aid with parsing the response. In `GetDict` function you can set the currencies you are interested in. In function `GetRate` you can specify the rate you are interested in. If you don't specify, it defaults to `"median_rate"`.

**Calling the API:**

> To get the rates for a particular date, make a[n] HTTP call to the
>   following URL:
>
> http://hnbex.eu/api/v1/rates/daily/?date=YYYY-MM-DD
>
> The date parameter is optional. If not set, the current date (today)
>   is used.

You can parse the `JSON` response with a [`JSON parser`](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) but I found it simpler to go with using `Split` to grab the required info from the `JSON` string. If you are familiar with `JSON` I will happily update with a JSON parsing example.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    'http://hnbex.eu/api/v1/
    Dim strJSON As String, http As Object, json As Object
    Const URL As String = "http://hnbex.eu/api/v1/rates/daily/"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        strJSON = .responseText
    End With
    'Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON) '<== You could parse the JSON using a JSON parse such as [JSONConverter][1]

    Dim currencyDict As Object
    Set currencyDict = GetDict

    Dim key As Variant, dictKeys As Variant, result As Variant
    For Each key In currencyDict.keys
        result = GetRate(strJSON, key)
        If Not IsError(result) Then currencyDict(key) = result
        result = vbNullString
    Next key

    PrintDictionary currencyDict

End Sub

Public Function GetDict() As Object '<== You could adapt to pass currencies as string arguments to the function. Or even a string array.
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "EUR", vbNullString
    dict.Add "CZK", vbNullString
    dict.Add "HRK", vbNullString
    dict.Add "HUF", vbNullString
    dict.Add "PLN", vbNullString
    dict.Add "RON", vbNullString
    dict.Add "RSD", vbNullString
    Set GetDict = dict
End Function

Public Function GetRate(ByVal json As String, ByVal key As Variant, Optional ByVal rate As String = "median_rate") As Variant
    Dim arr() As String, tempString As String
    On Error GoTo Errhand
    arr = Split(json, """currency_code"": " & Chr$(34) & key & Chr$(34))
    tempString = arr(1)
    tempString = Split(arr(1), Chr$(34) & rate & Chr$(34) & ":")(1)
    tempString = Split(tempString, ",")(0)
    GetRate = tempString
    Exit Function
Errhand:
    GetRate = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function

Public Sub PrintDictionary(ByVal dict As Object)
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.keys
        Debug.Print key & " : " & dict(key)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

### **Internet Explorer:**

You can use an loop with explicit wait for element to be present on page (or populated)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object
    Const WAIT_TIME_SECS As Long = 5
    t = Timer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.hnb.hr/en/core-functions/monetary-policy/exchange-rate-list/exchange-rate-list"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hTable = .document.getElementById("records_table")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > WAIT_TIME_SECS Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing

        If hTable Is Nothing Then
            .Quit
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        .Quit                                    '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a fan of `Clipboard`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot!

Comment: Pleasure. Glad it helped.